# Infinite Conjunction vs. Compactness

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How is what Quine (Methods of Logic, 1959, p. 254) called "the law of infinite conjunction" different from the compactness theorem for propositional logic?

The former states that if a finite or infinite set C of truth-functional formulas is consistent, then there is some truth-assignment that makes all members of C true.

Compactness states that a set of propositions is satisfiable if and only if every finite subset is satisfiable.

Comment: It sounds more like compactness for *propositional* logic - the semantics of first-order logic is much more complicated than just truth valuations. But I don't have a copy of Quine's book at hand. What are his "truth-functional formulas," exactly?

Comment: Basically YES; Quine is adapting to his own proof system the [Original proof of Gödel's completeness theorem for FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (see comment page 258).